# PHP for a single field in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using PHP to access a MYSQL database and I'm needing to extract data from a table. The problem is that there is only one field to be fetched.

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name);

        // Output error info if there was a connection problem
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
            die("Failed to connect to MySQL: ($mysqli->connect_errno) $mysqli->connect_error");

        $db = "SELECT username1 FROM Friends WHERE username2 = '"."$username"."' UNION SELECT username2 FROM Friends WHERE username1 = '"."$username"."'";

        $result = $mysqli->query($db) or
            die ("Wasn't able to search the database");

        while($result->fetch_field($row))
        {
            echo "<h1> $row </h1>";
        }
```

I guarantee that I am connected to my database. I also used $result->fetch_field() instead of $row in the parentheses. My main problem is that fetch_field returns an object but in all of the manuals on PHP they don't say how you extract the actual value that the field has.

Comment: I know it's probably really basic and I've missed the obvious but I just can't get it to work. I've tried fetch_row() as well and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your variable `$username` in your query is what you expect it to be? Your `SELECT` could be returning `0` rows.

You are using `$username` twice in your code.
First in your `mysqli`-

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name);
                                ---------
```

And again in your `SELECT` -

```
$db = "SELECT username1 FROM Friends WHERE username2 = '"."$username"."' UNION SELECT username2 FROM Friends WHERE username1 = '"."$username"."'";
                                                           ---------                                                               ---------
```

Try adding

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
  echo "<h1>".$row[0]."</h1>";}
}
else {echo "No Query / Returned 0 Rows";}
```

Comment: That was the problem, Sean. It was an improper placement of the $username reassignment. It makes me wish that PHP had variable declarations. Thank you very much!       For those curious, I used while($row = $result->fetch_row()) { echo "<h1> $row[0] </h1>"; } and it gave me the correct output.

Comment: I just saw the if statement! That would be a great idea to avoid future problems like this one.

Comment: I started using that type of `if` statement as an easy means to debug my scripts, as it lets me know that the connection is good, but either my query is wrong, or no rows match the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<h1>".$obj->username1."</h1>";
}
```

*The mysqli_fetch_object() will return the current row result set as an object where the attributes of the object represent the names of the fields found within the result set.*

It's a bit mad that there isn't a fetch_value($table, $column, $where) function

Comment: That doesn't give me any errors, which is great! But I don't get any output, which is sad. Lol. I know! It's so weird that you can't just fetch the value and be on your merry old way.

Answer (score 0):

try to fetch an array from the results, like this:

```
while($row = fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<h1> $row['username1'].''.$row['username2'] </h1>";
    }
```

I'm assuming that all records have both username1 and username2 NOT NULL and showing them side by side (as for example first name and last name).

Comment: I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING.
I'm guessing it means that $row['username1'] is not defined.

Comment: yes, see the edit. It is because I was using fetch_array instead of fetch_assoc, so it was expected to use numerical indexes instead of associative indexes.

Comment: also, why are we passing $row? Try with just fetch_assoc($result).